# Angular - trying to get div height on page load on element which content comes from api request

Tags: angular, fetch-api

On Init I am trying to get div height to calculate how many lines of text it has. The problem is that on page load `divHeight` is 0 and so the `numLines` will be 0 as well. Later when I start interacting on the page the `numLines` turns into a correct number of how many lines of text I have.

How can I prevent this from happening and get correct height from textElement div when div content (text) is fetched from API?

This is my current code:

```
 @ViewChild('textElement') textElementRef!: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Get the element containing the text
    const textElement = this.textElementRef.nativeElement;
    const divHeight = textElement.offsetHeight;
    console.log('divHeight', divHeight);

    const lineHeight = parseInt(getComputedStyle(textElement).lineHeight, 10);
    console.log(lineHeight);

    // Calculate the number of lines and store it in a variable
    this.numLines = Math.round(divHeight / lineHeight);
  }
```

Comment: Fetching external (api) data via subscription is an async action and there's no point checking response-bound template *before* the api response actually gets in. Thus, wrap your height-calculating code into a method and call that method from inside of the subscription, when the data is returned from api and all the template-bound variables are updated with api data..

Comment: What if it's reusable component and I have many different api calls? @MishaMashina

Comment: What exactly is your intent in counting lines? Generally not a good idea to track this kind of state behavior in javascript. This is likely something that should be handled in CSS. If you're going to do it anyways you'll probably need to hook into window resize events as well.

Comment: This limit's the lines of text if there is too much text(for example if there is 10 lines of text it will show 3) and it will add "read more" button. But when there is less than 3 lines of text the "read more" button shouldn't be visible. That's why I need to get how many lines of text there is with JS and sadly it's not possible with CSS @MarkClark

Comment: I think you might be better off using [max-lines](https://css-tricks.com/max-lines/) or `line-clamp` in CSS and for your javascript setting an arbitrary character limit that approximates your line limit. Much simpler implementation even if it there is a small threshold where a redundant "show more" is shown when text isn't truncated. Depends on how polished it needs to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solution I added ChangeDetectorRef and HostListener to impors and used them in my component.

```
 @ViewChild('textElement') expandableTextElementRef!: ElementRef;

 constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Get the element containing the text
    const textElement = this.textElementRef.nativeElement;
    const divHeight = textElement.offsetHeight;
    console.log('divHeight', divHeight);

    const lineHeight = parseInt(getComputedStyle(textElement).lineHeight, 10);
    console.log(lineHeight);

    // Calculate the number of lines and store it in a variable
    this.numLines = Math.round(divHeight / lineHeight);
  }
```